# New word from a rotation function

Tags: word, cipher

In the Caesar cipher a word is encoded by rotating the letters in the alphabet a given number of times, $N<26$. A word is the smallest sequence of phonemes that can be uttered in isolation with objective or practical meaning.

**Question.** What is the longest word with a sence that is obtained after the rotation function **rotN()**?

For example, if **the** is the original word then **rot19(the)=max** is a new word with a sense. The word's length is 3.

4-letters word: **rot23(frog)=cold**.

Comment: What counts as a word, exactly? (And I assume N can't be a multiple of 26?)

Comment: Word can be noun, verb... Yes, $N<26$. I updated the question.

Comment: I know the general meaning of "word" -- I mean, for this puzzle, what *exactly* counts as a word? If there's no clear way to determine what is and isn't a word, the question is opinion-based.

Comment: Answer is a word that can find a word meaning in the Britannica.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly obscure 8 letter answer

> [wiliwili](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wiliwili) and [corocoro](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/corocoro) which are inverse under application of ROT6/ROT20

Answer (score 3):

7 letters:

> 'nowhere' and 'abjurer' are each other's ROT13 inverses

Comment: Did you steal this from the Wikipedia article? I did... purpura ↔ Chechen is another 7 letter listed there either way.

Comment: I figured this out a while ago when gathering information for creating a new puzzle.

Comment: A better puzzler than I

Answer (score 2):

Also seven letters, but not listed in the preexisting answers:

> Since for our purposes a word is "the smallest sequence of phonemes that can be uttered in isolation with objective or practical meaning", I propose "myslayd" (put in a place that was thereafter forgotten), which under rot-6 is "Seyrgej" ([a man's name](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei)).

Answer (score 1):

7 letters :
Don't ask the meaning

> 23->SULPHUR::PRIMERO

> 22->LEVELER::HARAHAN

> 22->RISKIER::NEOGEAN

> 22->TETTERS::PAPPANO

> 20->MUU-MUU::GOO-GOO

> 20->POM-POM::JIG-JIG

> 19->BUMPILY::UNFIBER

> 18->JIG-JIG::BAY-BAY

> 16->GOO-GOO::WEE-WEE

> 16->WEE-WEE::MUU-MUU

> 14->BAY-BAY::POM-POM

> 13->ABJURER::NOWHERE

> 13->CHECHEN::PURPURA

Comment: But I want to know the meaning

Comment: :) google google